# Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Error: [firebase_messaging/failed-service-worker-registration] Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:61876/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:61876/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). .

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 327:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 337:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1386:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7

Code of the token part:

```
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
String? fCMToken;
Future<void> initNotification() async{

await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

if(kIsWeb){
  fCMToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken(
    vapidKey: "KEY IS GIVEN HERE"
  );
}else{
  fCMToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
}
debugPrint("Token ============> ${fCMToken}");
}
```